# How to not escape replacement text?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a template with this in it:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>{{ message|replace({"\r\n\r\n":'</p><p>', "\r\r":'</p><p>', "\n\n":'</p><p>'}) }}</p>
</blockquote>
```

With this input

> Woop-de-doo\r\nLa-dee-da\r\n\r\nFoo van der Bar\r\n\r\nMojo<script>alert('Test');</script>

it renders like this:

```
Woop-de-doo La-dee-da</p><p>Foo van der Bar</p><p>Mojo<script>alert('Test');</script>
```

Well, that's a shame, I wanted my replacement HTML to render. If you slap a `|raw` on the end, it works:

```
Woop-de-doo La-dee-da

Foo van der Bar

Mojo
```

Except it also runs the (potentially dangerous) script from the input text, which I obviously **don't** want to have happen.

How can I tell Twig to use my replacement text literally, but still keep the input text escaped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try using the php method nl2br ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

you can use it as a twig filter

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html

```
{{ "I like Twig.\nYou will like it too."|nl2br }}
```

if you want specifically to have the transformation you described and you want it to do a pre-escape and then to render in html you will have to write your own filter

for this let's see how `nl2br` is implemented

https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/11f9ebe8b6fb4d18d02591c4a042d1cab94b72eb/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L172

```
 new Twig_SimpleFilter(
   'nl2br',
   'nl2br',
   array('pre_escape' => 'html', 'is_safe' => array('html'))
 )
```

so now in order to write your own extension you can follow this tutorial

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

```
class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter(
                'doubleline2paragraph',
                array($this, 'doubleLine2Paragraph'),
                array('pre_escape' => 'html', 'is_safe' => array('html'))
            ),
        );
    }

    public function doubleLine2Paragraph($text)
    {
        // your transformation

        return $text;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

then registering it (as explained in the link above) so that you can use it

```
 {{ "your text" | doubleline2paragraph }}
```

Comment: It won't do what I want. I want double newlines to close and open new paragraphs, `</p><p>`, as my code demonstrates.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid having to write my own, but unless somebody comes along and proves you wrong, I'll accept this as the answer.